# Error moving a constant byte value into %ebx

Tags: assembly, x86-64, addressing-mode

I'm working through *Computer Systems, A Programmer's Perspective* (3rd edition), and Practice Problem 3.3 contains the following line:

```
movb $0xF, (%ebx)
```

I'm supposed to find out what's wrong with this line of x86-64 assembly, and the answer key states: "Cannot use %ebx as address register", which doesn't make sense to me. My understanding is that this line intends to copy 0xF to a location in main memory, however %ebx is a 32-bit register, memory addresses are 64 bits wide on 64-bit machines, and so %ebx cannot hold a memory address, therefore it cannot be dereferenced (dereferencing is what the parentheses around %ebx represent, correct?). However, looking a few pages back in the book (page 183, if you have it) there is an example detailing the five mov operand--destination combinations, one of which is:

```
movb $-17, (%esp)         Immediate--Memory, 1 byte
```

%esp is a 32-bit register just like %ebx! And this example shows a byte value being moved to a dereferenced 32-bit register! Which doesn't make sense to me, because how can %esp contain a 64-bit address? Do I completely misunderstand assembly?

Comment: You can address using 32 bits in 64 bit mode too, if you know your address is within the 32 bit range. Typically, stack isn't, so the `(%esp)` is dangerous.

Comment: Was the earlier example talking about 32bit x86 code?  You're right that 32bit address size is unwise in 64bit code, unless you have arranged for your addresses to be in the low 4GiB of virtual memory (e.g. Linux x32 ABI).  On normal Linux systems, the text, data and bss segments are mapped into the low 32bits of virtual address space, but the stack isn't.  Stackoverflow certainly gets questions where the answer is "you assembled a 32bit example into a 64bit program, so you segfaulted by truncating an address".

Comment: Thanks Jester and Peter Cordes, I didn't realize you could address using 32 bits in 64 bit mode. Also, no, I don't believe the example is talking about 32 bit x86 code because the 3rd chapter was completely rewritten for the 3rd edition to represent x86-64 assembly. Maybe I'll email the authors to add to the errata for the book. Thanks!!!

Comment: Old comment, but note I said "x32" which is still 64-bit code, just using 32-bit pointers to save D-cache footprint in pointer-heavy data structures.  It's an ILP32 ABI version of the x86-64 System V ABI.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI . (It never really caught on, so I'm not surprised this was a typo in a book rather than talking about x32, though.)  Anyway, "x32" is *not* a correct way to refer to legacy 32-bit mode, it means something else.  [The most correct way to refer to 32-bit and 64-bit versions of programs for x86-related CPUs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53364320)

Answer (score 8):

You are right that,

```
movb $-17, (%esp)         Immediate--Memory, 1 byte
```

should not be allowed. In fact the authors have posted this as a typo.
Check out their [errata list](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/errata.html) (Ctrl-F for "p. 183").

Comment: It's encodeable, but will usually fault unless the upper 32 bits of `%rsp` are zero.  This is the case if your stack is in the low 4G of memory.  The [Linux x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) uses 32-bit pointers in 64-bit mode (to save cache footprint in pointer-heavy code, and avoid REX prefixes when working with pointers), so this would be valid there.  Anyway, I think you meant to say it's not a good example.  Thanks for the update that this was an error in the book.

Answer (score 2):

For 64-bit x86; there is nothing wrong with the instruction `movb $0x0F, (%ebx)`. It assembles to 0x67, 0xC6, 0x03, 0x0F.

The book is wrong.

Note that all instructions can be bugs (simple example: using `add` when you wanted to use `sub`), and `movb $0x0F, (%ebx)` may be a bug (e.g. maybe the value was supposed to be `0xFF`, maybe it was supposed to use a different register, maybe it was supposed to use `rbx`, maybe it was supposed to be a `lea`, ..). This doesn't mean that it's always a bug (e.g. 32-bit addresses are perfectly legal and sometimes desirable in 64 bit code).

Comment: The instruction executes without generating "illegal instruction" exception. A more accurate explanation can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30291334/683727

Answer (score -2):

if ur machine is on x64, you can't access memory with %ebx (4bit) cause ur memory address is 8bit.