# Can't use %ebx as an address register

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

Why is that for the following assembly instruction in x86-64 AT&T format:

```
movb  $0xF,  (%ebx)
```

It produces an error claiming that %ebx cannot be used as an address register?

Comment: While that is valid and should not give an error (you forgot to specify the assembler you use unfortunately...) in 64 bit mode you should probably use `%rbx` to make sure you have a full size pointer.

Comment: If this is marked with the [tag:c] tag, please show the actual C code (the full inline assembly call).

Comment: This is AT&T syntax, not Intel syntax

Comment: Whoops, right. This is actually a problem from the book Computer Systems, 3rd edition and it notes that %ebx apparently shouldn't be used as a destination register.

Comment: You still haven't told us the assembler (I assume gnu `as`) and what error you get. I have tested with version 2.22 and no error is produced, instead I get machine code bytes `67 c6 03 0f`. The reason why you would not normally use `ebx` is that it is 32 bit so quite possibly only half of your pointer. Nevertheless if you are really sure that 32 bits are enough, the architecture does allow that.

Comment: @MichaelPetch but that won't produce an error, not even in inline assembly, unless you use constraints. Also, OP tagged `x86-64` so I do hope it is 64 bit code...

Comment: I guess the error message is not a real one. Seems this question is nearly identical to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633075/error-moving-a-constant-byte-value-into-ebx

Comment: @MichaelPetch nice find :)

Comment: @Jester, had your name all over it LOL ;-)

Comment: Also - if you really are using IA32 ELF, you need to be careful with `%ebx` - restoring it as the GOT pointer, IIRC. PIC code won't even let you use it as an inline asm constraint.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelPetch and Jester for the clarifications! The link that Michael pointed out is the same problem!